# Speeding up double/nested select query for IP lookups

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design

I'm trying to do a search for a client's IPs, then search all of those IPs for more clients. Essentially, I'm trying to see if a client has shared IP addresses with any other clients.

The issue I'm running into is that the query takes 25-30 seconds regardless of the data size it is operating on. I was wondering if there was a more effective query or table setup. We currently have over 6,300,000 rows in this table.

---

The query I currently have is:

```
select * from client_ip
where ip in(
    select ip from client_ip
    where id = "6" and last_login > "2017-04-26"
 )
```

This query will grab the IPs for client id 6 and look up all those IPs and list the rows where they occur. The outputted select list is the IPs of the client and other clients who have also had the same IP.

Example results:

[image: Results]

Table view of `client_ip`:

[image: Table view]

This table logs a new row with their user `id`, `ip`, `last_login` date, and the `count` (number of times they have been on that IP). Meaning that each IP a client has used is logged.

---

As I said above, I was wondering if there was a more effective query or table setup to speed up the query time.

(From comment)

```
CREATE TABLE player_ip (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL, 
    ip VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
    last_login TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
            DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    count INT(11) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (ip, id), 
    UNIQUE INDEX UNIQUE (ip, id)
) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: First, let's get clear what an IP is.  Is it a dotted quad (such as 1.2.3.4)?  Is it 131.?  Is it 132.224?  Is it 1.0.111?

Comment: Second, do you count this as a match:  216.111.222.33 versus 216.111.9.8?  If so, why?

Comment: A dotted quad. Matches need to be identical because I am wanting to see what clients have shared what exact addresses.

Comment: What are your DDL & query plans?

Comment: why are you using nested query,i think single query will give you the result.Its just select with where condition

Comment: @philipxy CREATE TABLE `player_ip` (
 `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
 `ip` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
 `last_login` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `count` INT(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ip`, `id`),
 UNIQUE INDEX `UNIQUE` (`ip`, `id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

Comment: select * from client_ip
    where id = "6" and last_login > "2017-04-26"

Comment: @MohanaPriyan That gives me the IPs that client has been on. I'm looking to find the clients who have been on those IPs.

Comment: @huhn your query give same result as my query in above comment.just try once

Comment: Please edit your question, comments are not for clarifications & are ephemeral. Also do not give a link, make your question self-contained.

Comment: The `UNIQUE` is unnecessary since a `PRIMARY KEY` is `UNIQUE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are id, ip, last_login, count the columns in `client_ip`?  If not *please* provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE client_ip`.

```
SELECT b.id, b.ip, b.last_login, b.count
    FROM client_ip AS a
    JOIN client_ip AS b  ON a.ip = b.ip
    WHERE a.id = "6"
      AND a.last_login >= "2017-04-26";
```

As a general rule, avoid `IN ( SELECT ... )`; turn it into a `JOIN`.  (A "self-join" in this situation.)

You will need

```
INDEX(id, last_login)
INDEX(ip)
```

(The `CREATE TABLE` will help me avoid conflicting with your existing indexes.)

Comment: This is currently working without messing with my indexes. Returns the expected results in 1.078 seconds compared to 24.485 seconds with my original query.

Comment: I commented my CREATE TABLE here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44212807/speeding-up-double-nested-select-query-for-ip-lookups#comment75437969_44212807

Comment: Adding `INDEX(id, last_login)` will probably make it  even faster.